# How to prevent variables set in a Controller from leaking from Views into Elements (isolate Elements' variable scope)?

Tags: cakephp

I've designed an Element that accepts optional arguments. Here's part of it:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My problem is that if a controller has a variable defined like this:

```
$this->set('title', 'Lorem ipsum');
```

The title will leak into the Element, setting the unwanted title?

I could think of a couple of workarounds:

1. Namespace Element variables, e. g. `$myElement_title` instead of `$title`.
2. Put all variables into a nested array, e. g.:

   ```
   $this->element('myElement', array('data' => array( 'title' => 'Foo Bar' )));
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   $this->element('myElement', array( 'title' => 'Foo Bar' ));
   ```

Both solutions are a nuisance. :(

PS I once tried the EmberJS framework. It has two features that resemble CakePHP's `$this->element()`: child Views and Components. The only difference between child views and components is that the former share the variable scope with the parent view and the latter have isolated scope. When i read about that, i was wondering why the difference. Well, with CakePHP i know the answer the hard way! :(

Comment: Use more unique names inside your elements, or always pass the variables in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, CakePHP does not provide this kind of functionality.

This is very unfortunate because i need two kinds of elements:

1. View partials. I want to split long bulky views into several files for the sake of maintainability and readability. The main view file contains HTML scaffolding while the partials contain the content, organized reasonably into separate files. The variable scope should be transparent. E. g. variables defined in the main view file should be available in elements. I also want to keep those files in a subfolder of the folder where the main view file is located.
2. Components. These are reusable blocks, just like what CakePHP elements are designed for. But they should have isolated scope: variables defined in controllers should not leak into them.

Unfortunately, CakePHP provides neither. CakePHP elements are a combination of these two variants, being as a result very unhandy:

1. Elements are a poor solution for view partials because:

   - Variables defined in the main view do not leak into the element.
   - Element files cannot be stored alongside view files.
2. Elements are a poor solution for components because:

   - Variables defined in the controller do leak into the element.

To work around the latter, i'm using this helper:

```php
class MyAwesomeHelper extends AppHelper {
    public function el($element_name, $args = array()) {
        return $this->_View->element($element_name, array('args' => $args));
    } // el()
}
class HHelper extends MyAwesomeHelper {}
```

It is a wrapper for `$this->element()` that passes all arguments as a single `$args` argument into `$this->element()`.

Example usage:

```php
<?php echo $this->H->el('foo', array('bar' => 'baz', 'quux' => true)); ?>
```

This is identical to:

```php
<?php
  echo $this->element('foo', array(
    array('bar' => 'baz', 'quux' => true)
  ));
?>
```

Inside the element, the arguments are to be accessed as keys of the `$args` array:

```php
<?php if (!empty( $args['title'] )): ?>
  <h2><?php echo $args['title']; ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you see, the `$args` is the only access point to the arguments of the element, and this variable is always passed into the element. This means that arguments will never be overridden by variables defined in the controller.